# mockk, get error when using mockkstatic for stub static function

Tags: android-unit-testing, mockk-verify

using io.mockk 1.11.0

having some class with `@JvmStatic` function

```
class LogUtil {
    @JvmStatic
    fun logData(jsonStr: String) {
        val jsonObj = getDataJson(jsonStr)
        if (jsonObj == null) {
            Log.e("+++", "+++ wrong json")
        }
        // ......
    }
}
```

data util

```
class DataUtil {
    @JvmStatic
    fun getDataJson(json: String): JSONObject? {
        return try {
            JSONObject(json)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            null
        }
    }
}
```

The test is to verify the `Log.e(...)`  is called when a null is returned from `getDataJson()`.

```
@Test
fun test_() {

    io.mockk.mockkStatic(android.utils.Log::class)
    io.mockk.mockkStatic(DataUtil::class)
    every { DataUtil.getDataJson(any()) } returns null  //<== error points to this line

    LogUtil.logData("{key: value}")

    verify(exactly = 1) { android.utils.Log.e("+++", any()) }
    
}
```

got error

```
io.mockk.MockKException: Failed matching mocking signature for
left matchers: [any()]
```

if change to `every { DataUtil.getDataJson("test string") } returns null`, it will get error

```
MockKException: Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock
```

How to use `mockkStatic` for a `@JvmStatic` unction?

Answer (score 0):

The use of mockkStatic is correct, but DataUtil is not static.

If your code is kotlin, must use object instead class:

object DataUtil { .. }
object LogUtil { .. }

PD: Use unmockkStatic in @After method for avoid side effects that may affect other test.